# jQuery Datatables- exact filtering returning nothing

Tags: jquery, search, datatables

I'm using the following to try and filter a column by an exact result (data). However, it returns no matches.

```
$('#orders').DataTable().column( 8 ).search("^" + data + "$", true, false, true).draw() ;
```

Using this code with the same input returns matches, though not exact.

```
$('#orders').DataTable().column( 8 ).search( data ).draw() ;
```

I don't understand why a result would not be returned. I think my issue is with the ^+data+$ part, though I'm not certain. Where might I be going wrong?

Thanks

Comment: can u create a plunkr for your issue ?

Comment: It should really work, there is nothing wrong with your regex search.

Comment: It's not working if I use the preserve quotes, either - "data" .